# How to parse xml feed - Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found

Tags: php, xml

i'm trying to parse an xml feed at http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml using simplexml like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml');
```

but getting error of - Start tag expected, '<' not found.

I'm presuming that this is because the xml isn't properly formatted?

Would anyone know how to parse this in php.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you load the content of the URL using cURL and then parse that content.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://smarkets.s3.amazonaws.com/oddsfeed.xml',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

This way you can see exactly what is getting parsed by SimpleXML. For additional debugging you can add the following lines before parsing the actual XML (taken from PHP website at http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($data);
if ($sxe === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: or use `file_get_contents`