# Get data with php from Url - Start tag expected, '<' not found in

Tags: php, web-services, soap

There is an webservice on:

http://carisastock.com/api/StockWebService

I want to get data from this url with php.

There is my php code below:

```
<?php
 $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://carisastock.com/api/StockWebService") or 
 die("Error: Cannot create object");
 echo $xml->Product[0]->Color . "<br>";
 echo $xml->Product[1]->Color; 
?>
```

But I get this error:
[image]

How can I get this data from url?

I can also use this url for single product:

carisastock.com/api/StockWebService/AJA0600045001PLS

Comment: This may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556270/how-to-parse-xml-feed-start-tag-expected-lt-not-found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just data from a remote path, you can use `file_get_contents` method in PHP.

```
$myXMLData = "http://carisastock.com/api/StockWebService";
$data = file_get_contents($myXMLData);

echo $data;
```

These data is in `json` format. If you want to get this json data into a usable format, just use `json_decode()` method to get json data to a PHP array.

Now, you can loop through that array to display your product items.

```
$data_arr = json_decode($data);

foreach ($data_arr as $data_item){
    echo $data_item->ID;
    echo $data_item->ProductName;
    echo $data_item->SKU;
    echo $data_item->Color;
    echo $data_item->Height;
    echo $data_item->Width;
    echo $data_item->Sections;
    echo $data_item->Quantity;
    echo $data_item->Category;
    echo $data_item->Price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. But I am new on Php. How can I get data for product; For example SKU = "ALD0500080006CHR"

Comment: I want to get quantity area with searching SKU. Then I will import them to external opencart database.